# Android show last activity after restarting an app

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an `Activity M` which is the **main** `Activity`. I can access an `Activity B` from `Activity M` and another `Activity C` from `Activity B`.

So `M` -> `B` -> `C`.

When I am currently in the `Activity C` and press the button on the bottom of my device, (the one which brings me back to the home screen. How is this button called anyway? ) and then click on my application icon again, it will start the `Activity M` instead of `Activity C`, although the last shown activity was `C`.

So `M` -> `B` -> `C` -> home screen through button click -> click on application Icon -> `M`

But what I want is `M` -> `B` -> `C` -> home screen through button click -> click on application Icon -> **`C`**

I hope my problem is clear. Does anyone know how to show my last shown activity before closing / pausing the application on application *restart*?

Comment: What is the launchmode of Activity M?

Comment: @AndroidWarrior "android.intent.action.MAIN"

Comment: @AndroidWarrior sry I mean singleTop